# Save and Continue in Django Forms

Tags: django, django-forms

I have created a django form which at the moment I can only save the POST. Would like to add Save and Add another button in my templates and views function. Has anyone found a solutions.

```
if request.method == "POST": 
    form = StktxnsForm(request.POST ) 
    if form.is_valid(): 
        new_txns = form.save(commit=False) 
        new_txns.created_by = request.user 
        new_txns.save() 
        return redirect('pending_transactions') 
else: 
    form = StktxnsForm() 
return render(request,'new_transaction.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 1):

You may think use AJAX function to save and continue without reload. Send 'POST' request to save data in Ajax. It will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I used like this in class-based view (vanilla method)

```
class PackageCreateView(View):

    def get(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        return render(request,'package/create_package.html')
    
    def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            if request.method == 'POST':
                data = request.POST
                name = data.get('name')
                detail = data.get('des')
                price = data.get('price')
                fname = Package.objects.all().filter(name=name)
                if fname:
                    messages.info (request,'sorry name already exits')
                    return redirect ('create_package')
                elif request.POST.get ('continue') :
                    pac = Package(name=name, detail=detail, price=price)
                    pac.save()
                    return redirect('create_package')
                else:
                    pac = Package(name=name, detail=detail, price=price)
                    pac.save()
                    return redirect('packagelist') 
            else:
                return redirect ('create_package')    
        else:
            return redirect('login')
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's one way to do it.

On your template:

```
<button type="submit" name="save_add" value="True">Save & Add another</button>
```

In your view:

```
if form.is_valid(): 
    new_txns = form.save(commit=False) 
    new_txns.created_by = request.user 
    new_txns.save() 
    if request.POST.get('save_add'):
        return redirect('create_transaction')
    return redirect('pending_transactions')
```

Comment: Hi @Rob L or @rob-l could you kindly explain in detail? I have created a form which redirected to the once the user has filled in the necessary information.                                                ``if request.method == "POST": form = StktxnsForm(request.POST ) if form.is_valid(): new_txns = form.save(commit=False) new_txns.created_by = request.user new_txns.save() return redirect('pending_transactions') else: form = StktxnsForm() return render(request,'new_transaction.html', {'form': form})`` and my url ``create_transaction,``

Comment: I edited my answer (and your question). Hope that clears it up.

Comment: @SJTG This is not the 'save and continue' concept. Save and Continue buttons should not redirect or reload page. Otherwise there is no continue :)

Comment: @notNowOnlyCoding One could argue about what Save and Continue buttons SHOULD do. But the way Django does it (e.g., in the admin) is to have 'Save' and 'Save and add another', both of which reload the page. So perhaps your philosophical objections based on what SHOULD be done should be taken up with the Django development team.